# In Jupyter Notebooks, the tooltip feature (shift + tab) works for some kernels (e.g. Python 3) but not others (e.g. Scala, Groovy). Is that expected?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, beaker-notebook

This is my first foray into Jupyter Notebooks. My background is in Java and Scala development in classical IDEs (e.g. IntelliJ, Eclipse).

I have Jupyter Notebook 5.0.0 installed with only two nbextensions: jupyter-js-widgets and beakerx.

My Python 3 notebooks allow me to use the tooltip feature (i.e. if I were to hit the combination shift+tab inside a method's parenthesis, I get expected arguments). However my Scala and Groovy notebooks do not (but I can run the cells just fine).

Is this expected or am I missing something? If this is expected, how do folks author in the notebooks without the ability to discover method arguments like you can in a standard IDE?

Comment: Answered here: https://github.com/twosigma/beakerx/issues/6598

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to run your statements (import module and declarations) by SHIFT + ENTER. Then it will show you tooltip after Shift + Tab was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

For the modules that you have imported, must run it first in cell. The key combination for the tooltip `SHIFT + Tab` will work.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://github.com/twosigma/beakerx/issues/6598

Tl;dr - BeakerX doesn't support this yet. Version 0.10.0 brings us one step closer.